# What is recommended practice for handling shared member variables in an async library method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, thread-safety

After reading a few articles on async await I now understand the following:

- As a library author, you should always use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to avoid making assumptions about the `SynchronizationContext` that the application is using
- The effect of `ConfigureAwait(false)` is that it will use the thread pool context, which means that the rest of the method could be run in any free thread
- You cannot use await in the body of a `lock` block

Let's assume that you are creating a library that has async API methods on a non-static class, and that class has some member variables that are shared across its API methods.  How do you write these methods in a way to ensure that the member variables are accessed in a thread safe way?

Comment: You would use one of the other synchronisation primitive E.g  like `SemaphoreSlim` ,which can be used in async methods

Comment: Could you provide a minimalistic example of the non-static class, and how its members are accessed by the rest of the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your needs, you can control concurrency in `async` methods with other *BCL* [synchronisation primitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives)

The easiest of which might be [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netcore-3.1)

> **Semaphore and SemaphoreSlim classes**
>
> The `System.Threading.Semaphore` and `System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim`
> classes limit the number of threads that can access a shared resource
> or a pool of resources concurrently. Additional threads that request
> the resource wait until any thread releases the semaphore. Because the
> semaphore doesn't have thread affinity, a thread can acquire the
> semaphore and another one can release it.
> SemaphoreSlim is a lightweight alternative to Semaphore and can be used only for synchronization within a single process boundary.

**Example**

```
private SemaphoreSlim _sync = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);

...

public async Task SomeMethodThatAccessSharedResources()
{
   await _sync.WaitAsync();
   try
   {
      // example of async call
      await Task.Delay(1000);
   }
   finally
   {

      _sync.Release();
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see.  So if I wanted to use the same lock for all the member variables in this class instance I'm asking about, I would do the above in every public API method

Comment: @WarrenOdonnell correct, as always though its probably best to research these options independently first and do your own due diligence

Answer (score 0):

What [Michael Randall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1612975/michael-randall) showed is more of a way of controlling access to certain parts of the code.

As mentioned on [synchronization primitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives), [Interlocked class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives#interlocked-class) can be used to change individual type member fields. According to the documentation

> The System.Threading.Interlocked class provides static methods that
> perform simple atomic operations on a variable. Those atomic
> operations include addition, increment and decrement, exchange and
> conditional exchange that depends on a comparison, and read operation
> of a 64-bit integer value.
>
> For more information, see the [Interlocked API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked?view=netcore-3.1) reference.